# CSS overlay on dynamic rows

Tags: php, css, overlay

I want to apply overlay css on rows dynamically.

Suppose I have list of 10 records. Now if admin enter 6 in text box and press submit button then I have to display first 6 records and remaining 4 are display under overlay layout.

Is it possible? How? 
[Please check screenshot for help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdkmY.png)

For information: I am using PHP and html code.

Comment: Add your some of your HTML/PHP code for the records and css if any so that we can help you out.

Comment: please check update.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You can create 10 divs (10 records) and give them `display: none` property.

If the user will insert 6 in the text box, you can change first 6 divs properties into `display: inherit` or `display: initial` using :nth-child property in CSS. It will be alot of work I assume.

Read more about nth property [here](http://nthmaster.com/).

Comment: Hi.Thank you.I don't want to hide any records.All records must be displayed event user add 6. But in that case I have to display remaining 4 under overlay layout.